# Removing class and attr at certain width issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a menu that drops down. After, 955 (desktop) width the dropdown menu stays open using javascript and I am unable to close it, which is what I want. This works great, so when on a  tablet the menu is closed but can be opened upon click, again this is what I want.

The problem occurs when I manually resize my screen width on desktop to tablet view, although its below 955 the menu stays open and I cant shut it. Please see this bootply example: http://bootply.com/86605

```
function checkWidth(init) {
    if ($(window).width() > 955) {
        $( "li#add" ).addClass( "open" );
        $('#remove').removeAttr("data-toggle");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth(true);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        checkWidth(false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that already built into the responsive bootstrap design?

Comment: No. We can show hide elements for specific devices. But What I'm trying to do here is keep the menu open for desktop and the user not being able to close it. However, on tablet I want it to behave normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function checkWidth() {
        if ($(window).width() > 955) {
            $("li#add").addClass("open");
            $('#remove').removeAttr("data-toggle");
        } else if ($(window).width() < 955) {
            $("li#add").removeClass("open");
            $('#remove').attr("data-toggle","dropdown");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the 'init' argument is for as it appears to be doing nothing but you need to add an another condition and remove the 'open' class.

```
function checkWidth(init) {
    if ($(window).width() > 955) {
        $( "li#add" ).addClass( "open" );
        $('#remove').removeAttr("data-toggle");
    } else if($(window).width() < 955) {
        $( "li#add" ).removeClass( "open" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that, however, by adding that it wont let me open the nav on tablet as it relies on the class "open" to open.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkWidth(init)
{/*If browser resized, check width again */
if ($(window).width() < 640) {
$('.second_menu_mid').addClass('rmm');
}else {if (!init) {  $('.second_menu_mid').removeClass('rmm');
} }}
$(document).ready(function() {
checkWidth(true);
$(window).resize(function() {
checkWidth(false);
});});
```